# Advantage of using CopyStreamListener?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

if i use the sample solution below for ftp upload/download, i can obtain the total bytes written/read from the stream to the socket buffer(correct me if i'm wrong). Compare this way of getting the bytes written/read versus using CopyStreamListener, which way is closer to the point where bytes is actually being sent over the network? Or this 2 approach is the same?

```
InputStream readStream = this.ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile);
int totalBytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = readStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
  totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways should be equivalent if what you want to achieve is simply counting the transferred bytes. However, using a listener has a design advantage in that you separate concerns better: One part of the code transfers the data, the other part accumulates statistics (and usually cooperates more closely with the user interface code than the transferrring code should do).

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for the answer. My concern is more to whether CopyStreamListener is triggered upon bytes being sent over to the network. To my understanding, the moment we use read/write function of InputStream/OutputStream, the bytes are only being send to the socket buffer and it is not actually out to the network yet. When i look at [link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/io/CopyStreamListener.html), I'm not sure if it means the copying of bytes from stream to socket buffer. If it is, then i guess it is equivalent like you say.

Comment: If you look at the source code of `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` and `org.apache.commons.net.io.Util`, you'll see that it also just uses `InputStream` and `OutputStream` instances to transfer data. `Util.copyStream()` is basically just the code in your question with a listener being called after each chunk has been transferred. In portable Java code, it's not getting any more low-level than using a `java.net.Socket` instance, which doesn't tell you how many bytes have actually left the socket buffer, so using a `CopyStreamListener` cannot give you more information.